# What is significance of cloth being tied to tree in this Sri. Shanskaracharya movie

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

I come across a scene at 29.13 second in the below movie on Shree Shankaracharya where he tied a cloth to tree.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-b6InzqxrrQ

What is significance of this cloth?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about youtube should be addressed to the youtube authors, not to this forum.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda The question isn't about Youtube or Youtube videos. It is about the content of a particular Youtube video and the content is related to Adi Shankara/Hinduism. That's why one can such questions here too.